# Registering for AppleEvents

Tags: c, applescript, appleevents

I'm trying to get started with AppleEvents. I've this simple registration and handle with logs:

```
static OSErr HandleOpenApplication(const AppleEvent* event, AppleEvent* ev, SRefCon sr)
{
    LOG_HIGH("@@@@@@@@ Got Apple Event @@@@@@@");
    return 0;
}

static OSErr InstallAppleEventHandlers()
{
    OSErr err = 0;
    err = AEInstallEventHandler(typeWildCard, typeWildCard,
                                NewAEEventHandlerUPP(HandleOpenApplication), 0, false); // 1
    require_noerr(err, CantInstallAppleEventHandler);
CantInstallAppleEventHandler:
    LOG_HIGH("@@@@@@@@ Registered Apple Event with " << err <<" code @@@@@@@");
    return err;
}
```

I've used wild card identifiers to get all the events.

After running my application I'm getting the log of successful registration.

Then, I'm running this AppleScript to send an Event:

```
tell application "System Events" to get name of every process

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "MyApp"
        run
    end tell
end tell
```

But I'm not getting the event in my app. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The script you'll wrote will send an AppleEvent to the application System Events, that is the application you're targeting. So what you need to do is change yourscript to something like:

```
tell application "MyApp" to launch
```

Also you should reply to event `ascr/noop`, instead of `****/****` (typewildcard/typewildcard).

Comment: This is the only way i found to address "MyApp" other ways AppleScript Editor don't know "myApp"

Comment: No, but a dialog appears and then you need to choose your application.